# htaccess rewrite rule not working correctly

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

#profile view
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1
```

When i go to my url and type `http://www.mysite.com/username`

then in **profile.php** file i have

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
    die();
?>
```

and it prints out

```
Array ( [id] => profile.php )
```

where it should have printed out

```
Array ( [id] => "username" )
```

So i guess there is something wrong in my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add QSA at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: @fxuser hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#profile view
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)?$ profile.php?id=$1
```

try that

EDIT:

RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA]

OR

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)?$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA]

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L] try that

Comment: the thing is that i want dots(.) to be able to be put in the URL and when i add them in the pattern it breaks and displays that id=profile.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /profile.php?id=$1
```

Comment: now im getting `internal server error` message, removing / from /profile.php displays the `Array ( [id] => profile.php )`